# PHPMailer include PHP Template returns 1 in the email

Tags: php, email

I' am on a email template where the email template will be dynamic based. So I' am making the template a PHP file and including the content using [INCLUDE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function in PHP. The email goes go through but I receive 1 in my email.

**PHP**

```
ob_start();
$preview_contents = include( get_template_directory() . '/framework/newsletters/includes/preview.php' );
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

**PHPMAILER**

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Host       = $host;
    $mail->Username   = $username;
    $mail->Password   = $pass;
    $mail->SetFrom("no-reply@xxxxx.com", "Pacific xx");
    $mail->AddAddress($subscribers_preview_email);
    $mail->Subject = $subscribers_subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($preview_contents);
    if($mail->Send()){
        die("1 | An preview email has been sent to you.");
    } else {
        die("0 | There was an error, please try again later.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this portion of your code

```
$mail->MsgHTML($preview_contents);
```

to look like this

```
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
```

I think that will work for you

Comment: But still the global WordPress variables like 'site_url()' is not working inside the PHP script.

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about wordpress.  Are other regular php variable and functions executing in the script.  If so, it would seem that you have not initialized the wordpress specific vars